# Comparing two ArrayList using Gson?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, string-comparison, gson

I am trying to compare two ArrayList< Map< String, Object>> objects but the problem is that I need to compare them in different app sessions. So I am saving the first ArrayList in SharedPreferences after converting it to String using Gson. Then I query the string in next session to compare it. I tried converting it back to ArrayList then comparing it with the list generated during the new session. Also tried converting the new list into json and then comparing both texts. But the result is same. Below is the relevant code:

Declaration:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> tweetMapArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then in some method :

```
List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(params[0], new Paging(1, 200));
tweetMapArray.clear(); // I am also reusing it
for (twitter4j.Status status : statuses) {
    Map<String, Object> valuesToPutInMarker = new HashMap<>();
    valuesToPutInMarker.put("id", status.getId());
    valuesToPutInMarker.put("status", status.getText());
    tweetMapArray.add(valuesToPutInMarker);
}
```

Now saving `tweetMapArray` in `SharedPreferences`:

```
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(tweetMapArray);
editor = configData.edit();
editor.putString("tweetData", jsonStr);
editor.apply();
```

Querying data:

```
private boolean seeIfTheDataIsNew() {
    String dataFromSharedPreferences = configData.getString("tweetData", null);
    Type collectionType2 = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>>() {
        }.getType();

    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> oldTweets = gson.fromJson(dataFromSharedPreferences, collectionType2);

    String jsonStr = gson.toJson(tweetMapArray);
    return jsonStr.equalsIgnoreCase(dataFromSharedPreferences);

    // OR

    return !(oldTweets.containsAll(tweetMapArray) && tweetMapArray.containsAll(oldTweets));
}
```

Here, both methods in last two lines return true. In the testing sample, they should return false.